# C, Reading double values from text file

Tags: c

Hi just getting some weird outputs from trying to read the inputs as double values in C. This issue does not occur when the inputs are integers is there anyway to make it work with double?

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    int main(void)
    {
        double a, b, c, d, i;
        FILE *inp;
        inp = fopen("C:\\Users\\student\\Documents\\Visual Studio2012\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication3\\test.txt", "r");
        i = fscanf(inp, "%f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);
        while (i != EOF)
        {
            printf("a = %f & %d \n", a, i);
            printf("b = %f & %d \n", b, i);
            printf("c = %f & %d \n", c, i);
            printf("d = %f & %d \n", d, i);
            printf("%d \n", EOF);
            i = fscanf(inp, "%f %f %f %f", &a, &b, &c, &d);
        }

        fclose(inp);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Always check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: Also `while (i != EOF)` is weak.  `i` could have the value of `1` and then`printf("b = %f & %d \n", b, i);` is undefined behavior.  Better to do `while (i == 4)`

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out, the `%f` in `fscanf` should be `%lf`

Answer (score 4):

Change the specifier to `%lf` in `fsacnf` and `printf` statements. Like this -

```
fscanf(inp,"%lf %lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

Other problems -

1.Also `i` is declared as `double` but in `printf` you print it with specifier `%d` ,so you pass wrong argument -

```
printf("a = %f & %d \n", a, i); // similar in all printf's
```

So according to me  declare `i` as `int` and then print it.

2.Also you should always check return of `fopen` so check it.