# Reading doubles form a file in C

Tags: c, file, double

I'm trying to read doubles from a file in C but it is turning out to be quite a nightmare. When I want to read ints or characters, I don't seem to encounter any problem whatsoever, however doubles seem to be hard to work with.

So, let's say I've got a file with two columns and four rows of double numbers and I want two vectors to keep all the data in each column. My code would be:

```
int main(void){

    double v1[4],v2[4];
    FILE *f;
    int i;

    f=fopen("hola.rtf","r");
    if(f==NULL){
            printf("Error fitxer!\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            fscanf(f,"%le",&v1[i]);
            fscanf(f,"%le",&v2[i]);
            printf("%le %le\n",v1[i],v2[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
```

But all values printed are 0... Any ideas/tips?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is that an RTF file?? (Rich text Format). Then this won't work as you have to parse the RTF. Dump/view the file in binary to determine its format.

Comment: Please show the first 3-4 lines of `hola.rtf`.

Comment: And check the return value of `scanf` to determine if it succeeded in reading the double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C, Reading double values from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345924/c-reading-double-values-from-text-file)

Comment: Without seeing your file format, this question is almost impossible to answer.

Comment: Please, share the result of `hexdump hola.rtf | head -n 10`.

P.S. Btw, be careful with `fopen`, it seems you should use `rb` mode, not `r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not check the return value from the [`fscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html), so you don't know whether it converted (and read) the data or not.

Furthermore, the specifier for `double` for [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) is `%e` (or `%f` or `%g`, depending on which format you want); `%le` is not a valid specifier in C, so if your program prints anything, it is because your compiler or C library accepts `%le`. (Whatever format it understands it as, is probably not `double`, though.)

---

Here is how you should read the doubles:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define  COUNT  4

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "hola.rtf";
    FILE *input;
    double v1[COUNT], v2[COUNT];
    int i;

    input = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        if (fscanf(input, " %le %le", &(v1[i]), &(v2[i])) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid data in %s.\n", filename);
            fclose(input);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        printf("Read %e and %e from %s.\n", v1[i], v2[i], filename);
    }

    if (ferror(input)) {
        fclose(input);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading %s.\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (fclose(input)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing %s.\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("All %d pairs of doubles read successfully.\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Many programmers believe that they can add error checking later back in. This is just not practical; what they normally end up with, is code with no or very few error checks in place. Yet, wouldn't you, as an user, want to know when the program malfunctions, and produces garbage instead of sane results? I definitely do, and so do all those I know that use the code to do actual work. It is an important habit to get into, because if you learn not to do it, it is very difficult to learn to do it afterwards.

The level of error checking can of course be discussed. I'm sure many members here consider the `ferror()` check and checking the result of `fclose()` as "unnecessary". It is true that they do not fail *in normal, typical operation*. It is possible for a programmer to never see either of them fail, ever. However, when they do fail -- say, someone ends up running your code on a FUSE filesystem which can report an error at close time --, the checks can mean the difference between tons of garbage and an early warning that something is wrong.

If you happen to agree with my sentiment (about semi-paranoid error checks being benign, and sometimes very useful to users), consider the following variant of your code, that reads all double pairs from a file specified on the command line to a dynamically allocated array:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} vec2d;

/* Read all 2D vectors from stream 'input',
   into a dynamically allocated array.
   (Similar to POSIX.1 getline(), but with double vectors.)
   If *dataptr is not NULL, and *sizeptr > 0,
   it will initially be used (but reallocated if needed).
   Returns the number of vectors read,
   or 0 with errno set if an error occurs.
*/
size_t vec2d_readall(FILE *input, vec2d **dataptr, size_t *sizeptr)
{
    vec2d *data;
    size_t size;
    size_t used = 0;

    if (!input || !dataptr || !sizeptr) {
        /* At least one of the parameters is NULL. */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return 0;
    }

    if (ferror(input)) {
        /* input stream is already in error state. */
        errno = EIO;
        return 0;
    }

    if (!*dataptr || !*sizeptr) {
        /* *dataptr is NULL, or *sizeptr == 0,
           so we initialize them to empty. */
        *dataptr = NULL;
        *sizeptr = 0;
    }
    data = *dataptr;
    size = *sizeptr;

    while (1) {

        if (used >= size) {
            /* We need to grow the data array. */

            /* Simple allocation policy:
               allocate in sets of roughly 1024 vectors. */
            size = (used | 1023) + 1021;
            data = realloc(data, size * sizeof *data);
            if (!data) {
                /* Realloc failed! */
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return 0;
            }

            *dataptr = data;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        if (fscanf(input, " %lf %lf", &(data[used].x), &(data[used].y)) != 2)
            break;

        /* One more vector read successfully. */
        used++;
    }

    /* If there was an actual I/O error, or
       the file contains unread data, set errno
       to EIO, otherwise set it to 0. */
    if (ferror(input) || !feof(input))
        errno = EIO;
    else
        errno = 0;

    return used;
}
```

Because the `vec2d_readall()` function always sets `errno` (to `0` if no error occurred), using the above function to read all double pairs from standard input as 2D vectors is very simple:

```
int main(void)
{
    vec2d     *vectors = NULL;
    size_t num_vectors = 0;
    size_t max_vectors = 0;

    size_t i;

    num_vectors = vec2d_readall(stdin, &vectors, &max_vectors);
    if (errno) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Read %zu vectors from standard input,\n", num_vectors);
    printf("with memory allocated for up to %zu vectors.\n", max_vectors);

    for (i = 0u; i < num_vectors; i++)
        printf("%f %f\n", vectors[i].x, vectors[i].y);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A little bit of extra effort spent in writing `vec2d_readall()` simplified our `main()` a lot. Plus, if we ever find we need a similar function to read 3D vectors, we only need to add a `typedef struct { double x; double y; double z } vec3d;`, and make some very small changes to the `vec2d_readall()` to turn it into `vec3d_readall()`.

Most importantly, we can rely on `vec2d_readall()` to *fail* if there is any kind of issue with the data. We could add error reporting, instead of just `break;`ing out of the loop.

If you wonder about the [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) mentioned in a comment, it is a POSIX.1-2008 standard function, that allows C programmers in POSIXy systems to read unlimited-length input lines. It is similar to `fgets()`, but with dynamic memory management.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you very much!